# What is the best way to debug stored procedures (and write sprocs that are easier to debug)?

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures

What are good methodologies for creating sprocs that reduce the pain of debugging? And what tools are out there for debugging stored procedures?

Perhaps most importantly, what are indications to look out for that errors are happening in a sproc and not in the code? I hope I'm not all over the board too terribly bad here. Votes for answers to any of the above. Thanks.

For what it's worth, I work in a .NET environment, SQL servers.

Answer (score 10):

One technique I use in stored procedures to make them easier to debug (without IDE or debuggers) for SQL Server 2005 procedures:

I add an input parameter named @Debug = 0 (defaulted to 0 = off) at the end of the parameter list for the procedure.

I then add if (@Debug = 1) print '...';

statements in the code at key junctures to display any useful internal values etc.

Yes, it's "old school" and debuggers that let you "walk the code" are great - but this works for anyone from any SQL tool (including anyone debugging without your same IDE).

Ron

Comment: I use the same approach but am curious: How about when sending these procedures to production, do you leave them or remove them? Any performance penalties?

Answer (score 8):

Another technique I use for both simple log output and debugging is to create a table variable at the top of the procedure:

```
   --**************************************************************************
   -- Create a log table variable to store messages to be returned to the
   -- calling application.
   --**************************************************************************
   declare @log             as table ( msg  varchar(MAX) );

then

     insert into @log values ('Inserted a new DVO Order into IRMA, order id: [' + convert(varchar(10), @@IDENTITY ) + ']');
etc.

then ...

   select msg from @log;
end
```

at the end of the procedure - this depends on how well the calling application logs output from your procedure call, but the app I wrote logs it all. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly suggest that you take a look at the built in tooling in SQL management studio.

i have written a pretty detailed blog post about it here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/11/23/debugging-sql-queries-function-amp-stored-procedures-with-sql-management-studio

basically the gist of it is that you enter you sql query to execute your stored procedure, and instead of pressing F5 or hitting the exclamation, you hit the play button and use F10 and F11 to step through and step into your stored procs.

very very handy - and no one seems to use it.

Comment: +1: Wow. It's been at least five years since I've revisited stored procedure debugging. I didn't know about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[TSQLUnit](http://tsqlunit.sourceforge.net/)

This is a unit testing framework for SQL Server. Not exactly a classic debugging tool but it does allow you to write unit tests for your stored procedures which can help tremendously in identifying bugs and to validate expected behaviors.

For example, If you have a buggy stored proc then you can write some unit tests to understand how it is failing. Also, if you make a change to your SQL code you can validate that your changes did not break anything else or at least tell you where a problem lies.

If something is hard to test then it might be a good indication that your stored proc might be doing too much and could benefit if it were be broken up into more focus and targeted procs. These procs should then become relatively easier to debug and maintain in the long run.

Comment: Agreed, we have been using DbFit and Fitness for about 8 months now and I can't imagine ever having lived without it.

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed a lot of suggestions on using different environments and techniques to debug SQL procs, but no one has mentioned [DBFit](http://benilovj.github.com/dbfit). If you are not familiar with [Fit](http://fit.c2.com/) and [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) then do yourself a favor and look them up. Using these three tools you can quickly build yourself an entire suite of acceptance tests that will give you peace of mind knowing you can refactor with impunity.

DBFit is simply a series of Fit Fixtures that can be used to exercise a database. Using Fitness you can write as many permutations of calls onto your stored proc as you want to create tests for.

This isn't debugging per se, but you would be amazed at how quickly you can pinpoint a problem once you have an entire battery of tests against a single stored proc. A failing test will lead you directly to the problem and give you the exact context with which it failed so there is no guess work. On top of it all, you can now refactor your stored procs without fear because you will simply have to re-run the tests to ensure you didn't break anything.

Answer (score 2):

For tools, you can use Visual Studio to debug SP.
If the stored proc has long logic, you can refactor it, create separate stored proc, and call it from your main stored proc. This will help to narrow down your testing also, and ease you to find which part of the queries is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a personal preference, but I find it extremely difficult to read SQL queries that are all slapped onto one long line. I prefer the following indentation style:

```
SELECT
    [Fields]
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    x = x
```

This simple practice has helped me out a lot when writing stored procedures for a brand new database schema. By breaking up the statements onto many lines it becomes easier to identify the culprit of a bug in your query. In SQL Server Management Studio, for example, the line number of the exception is given, so you can target problematic code much quicker.

Be easy on your fellow developers...don't cram 800 characters of a SQL query onto one line. You'll thank yourself later if a database field name or datatype changes and nobody emails you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of patterns I have seen successfully used are 'diagnostic' or 'test' modes and logging.

test or diagnostic modes are useful when you are doing dynamic SQL execution. Make sure you can see what you are going to execute. If you have areas where you need (or should) be checking for errors consider logging to a table with enough details so you can diagnose what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sql server debugging, but I've found that to be a pain in anything but the most direct of situations (debugging on a local server, etc). I've yet to find something better than print statements, so I'll be monitoring this thread with interest.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Maybe some entrepreneur out there can make some sorely-needed tools.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some advice that was reiterated to me today - if you're adding a join to an important query on the production database, make sure it's safe when there is a null field in the joining table.

```
LEFT JOIN
```

I broke an important page for 20 minutes before we figured out that it was my small, rushed stored procedure change.

And make sure you test your procedures when you make a change. To do this, I like to put a simple test query in the comments of the  procedure. Obvisouly, I failed to do this today :-(

```
/************************************
  MyProcName

  Test:
  -----
  exec MyProcName @myParam
*************************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but if you are already in a .Net environment LINQtoSQL has greatly reduced the amount of stored procs I write/use/need to debug.

The difficulty of debugging SQL is one of the reasons programming business logic in LINQ is my new preferred practice .

Comment: That is something of which I am ignorant. I'll have to spend some time with LINQ. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 Management Studio's integrated debugger made step-wise debugging a cinch (compared judo required to figuring out how to get VS2005 + SQL to debug)

Comment: Can I assume that Server Manager Express doesn't have this feature?

Comment: @ MrBoJangles: even if Express edition does not have it, you can buy a developer edition (functionally equivalent to the Enterprise edition) for 50$ !

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Ron's Logging we call a logging proc through all other stored procedures to assist in getting tracing on all calls.
A common BatchId is used throughout to allow tracing for a certain batch run.
Its possibly not the most performant process but it does help grately in tracking down faults.
Its also pretty simple to compile summary reports to email admins.

ie.

```
Select * from LogEvent where BatchId = 'blah'
```

Sample Call

```
EXEC LogEvent @Source='MyProc', @Type='Start'
, @Comment='Processed rows',@Value=50, @BatchId = @batchNum
```

Main Proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogEvent]
    @Source varchar(50),
    @Type varchar(50),
    @Comment varchar(400),
    @Value decimal = null,
    @BatchId varchar(255) = 'BLANK'
AS

IF @BatchId = 'BLANK'
  SET @BatchId = NEWID()

  INSERT INTO dbo.Log
    (Source, EventTime, [Type], Comment, [Value],BatchId)
  VALUES
    (@Source, GETDATE(), @Type, @Comment, @Value,@BatchId)
```

Moving forward it would be nice to leverage the CLR and look at calling something like Log4Net via SQL.  As our application code uses Log4Net it would be advantageous to intergrate the SQL side of processes into the same infrastructure.